# Get loop when check cookie in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cookies, hapi.js

This is my code at the client side. What I'm trying to achieve is quite clear. If the user has the cookie it is authenticated otherwise it is redirect to an auth endpoint at the server

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('App', [
      'ui.router',
      'ngResource',
      'ngCookies'        ])
    .run(['$window', '$cookies', '$state', function($window, $cookies, $state) {

      if($cookies['cookie-app']) {
        console.log('authenticated');
      } else {
        $window.location.href = "http://" + $window.location.host + "/auth/facebook";
      }
    }]);
})();
```

This is the code a the server side made by using Hapijs

```
module.exports = function(request, reply) {

  if (request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
    console.log(request.auth.credentials.profile.raw);
    request.auth.session.set(request.auth.credentials.profile.raw);
    return reply.redirect('http://localhost:8080');
  }

  reply('Not logged in').code(401);
};
```

The cookie is set correctly but I don't get true in the if then I get an infinite loop. my scenario is the following. nginx serves angularjs file and it acts a reverse proxy for the hapijs server.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: You mean 'but *if* I don't get true'? And do you really need to redirect the user? Can't you just use ajax to set the cookie?

Comment: I mean that the condition is never resolved to true then the client calls in loop the server endpoint. I set the cookie at the server side.

Comment: The auth takes place at the server side. the cookie is then saved at the server side and the client should just check its existence nothing more

Comment: The last time i tried using $cookies in Angular I got so annoyed with it that I just opted for a jQuery plugin to deal with them. So I don't know, maybe $cookies is just a little bit buggy.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to disable `httpOnly` flag on the options of hapi-auth-cookie